# document.Cookie is ignored by Chrome if path is set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I want to create a cookie that will not be sent to the server due to some legacy code in our app that cleared the content of the cookies upon login. To accomplish that I want to set the path of the cookie to something arbitrary.

I'm trying to set a cookie is JS using the following code:

```
document.cookie = "test=this is a test; Domain=mydomain.com; Path=/localcookie; Expires=Mon, 05 Apr 2021 21:02:42 GMT"
```

This line works fine in Firefox but is being ignored in Chrome (v80). If I remove the Path parameters or set it to "/" the cookie is created but not with the path I want.

Is this a a limitation in Chrome, a security thing, a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you testing your site locally or is it being served from the specified domain? I have had similar 'issues' with Chrome. Some behaviour also depends on the site being served using https or not. I would check that first.

Comment: A cookie that isn't sent to the server? Have you considered simply using localStorage instead?

Comment: I'm serving the page from local IIS server.

Comment: @C14L, the reason I'm not using local storage is because i need the information in the cookie to be available to all apps in my domain, regardless of the sub-domain. For example I want apps1.mydomain.com and apps2.mydomain.com both to have access to the cookie, something, AFAIK, cannot be accomplished with local storage.